# Delete tags from feature branch

Tags: git, git-tag

We are using Bitbucket for maintaining our code.
We have policy to not to push tags.

I have created a feature branch named **myFeature** and fetched on local.

Made some changes in files committed and pushed.

Later found that there were tags on local:

[image]

Deleted the tags from local:
[image]

How can I delete the tags from **myFeature** branch?

Comment: Why are you deleting the tags? Deleting a tag is the same no matter where it is (locally) `git tag -d <tag-name>`

Comment: I have deleted the tags so in next push those tags should not go in remote.

Comment: A standard push does not push tags?

Comment: Why not `git tag -d <tagname>` as noted in the [Git-docu](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging)

Comment: Tags are usually detached to commits. They are independent from any branch.

Comment: @evolutionxbox I believe the tags are not pushed as per: https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/inspecting-a-repository/git-tag. As mentioned in the page: "By default, git push will not push tags. "

Comment: @वरुण sorry, that's what I was saying. I'm confused why you're worried about accidentally pushing tags, but git doesn't push them unless you specifically tell it to

Comment: I was concerned because earlier some people pushed tags and it created big issue. We were not able to use Bitbucket for a week due to slowdown. Maybe they were using SourceTree with "Push all tags to remote" checked.

Comment: It seems like it might be worth figuring out what's creating all these tags, since you apparently don't actually need them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure this answers your actual issue, but here is an answer to the question :

> How do I list tags pointing at any commit in the history of `myFeature` branch ?

One way is to combine `git rev-list` and `git for-each-ref --points-at` :

```
git rev-list myFeature |\
  xargs -L1 git for-each-ref refs/tags --format="%(refname)" --points-at
```

- `git rev-list myFeature` will list all commits in the history of `myFeature`
- `git for-each-ref refs/tags --format="%(refname)" --points-at xxx` will list all the tags that point at commit `xxx`
- `xargs -L1 ...` is one way to call the command on the right once for each line coming from the left

You should get a list formatted like this :

```
$ git rev-list myFeature | xargs -L1 git for-each-ref refs/tags --format="%(refname)" --points-at
refs/tags/SFDCxxxx1
refs/tags/SFDCxxxx2
refs/tags/SFDCxxxx3
 ...
```

---

As for deleting them :

Once you have checked that you listed only tags you want to delete, you can use this list to delete tags from the remote :

```
... | xargs git push origin -d
```

To delete tags locally, you need to either get rid of the leading `refs/tags/`, or use `update-ref -d`  :

```
# one way : replace the '--format' option of 'git for-each-ref' :
... --format="%(refname:short)" ... | xargs git tag -d

# another way : feed 'refs/tags/SFDCxxx' references to 'update-ref -d' one by one
... | xargs -L1 git update-ref -d
```

Comment: Thanks for taking time. I believe tags are not pushed by default with git push doesn't push changes. Your answer may be helpful for folks who have accidently pushed the changes. As you have answer the question title, I am accepting your answer.

Comment: Tags will not be pushed by default, but they will be fetched : if you run `git fetch origin myFeature`, unless you specify `--no-tags`, all remote tags pointing to some commit in the history of your branch will also be fetched. I suggested the "delete remote tags" part to address this possible issue.